# Embedding Node.js into a C Application (for Pure Data)

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, embed, puredata

I am looking into the feasibility of embedding Node.js into a C application. Pure Data is a graphical programming language which is written in C. I am looking to write a C extension for the program that can call nodejs functions. If this is not possible, I am seeing if there are other alternatives for embedding Javascript into a C application. Ideally, the embeddable Javascript would support the latest Javascript specs.

Comment: Maybe you could use [node addon API](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api) which is a C/C++ interface with NodeJS environment. You can check [some example here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples) not sure it matches your requirements though